# Limit S3 partitions scanned by each execution of Structured Streaming query

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We currently upload a bunch of Avro files to S3 that are partitioned by the hour of upload, and we are looking to ETL them into Parquet and repartitioned by the customerId of the event.

We've POCed a solution using spark structured streaming and it seems to be semantically correct. Our code has a bunch of queries that look like

```
Dataset<Row> sourceStream = sparkSession.readStream()
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .load("/avro/input/path");

sourceStream
  .drop("ingestion_hour")
  .withColumn("c_id", new Column("customer_id"))
  .repartition(new Column("c_id"))
  .writeStream()
  .trigger(Trigger.Once())
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
  .format("parquet")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint/path/")
  .partitionBy("c_id")
  .start("/parquet/output/path");
```

However, there seems to be a problem where the number of files under the `/avro/input/path` prefix is constantly increasing, thus causing each execution of the ETL to take longer and longer to list the files in S3 in order to compute new files.

I tried to split up the singular streaming query into multiple streaming queries that consume from each hour, e.g. `/avro/input/path/ingestion_hour=yyyy-MM-dd-HH` and output to the same sink of `/parquet/output/path` with a checkpoint path `/checkpoint/path/yyyy-MM-dd-HH`. I can then limit the job to execute only queries for the past, say, 12 hours. However, the job doesn't seem like sharing a sink between multiple queries is the correct thing to do as most of the records don't show up in the output.

I'm wondering if there's some way to get this approach to work or if there's a different approach to limit the number of files listed?

Comment: Use the SQS service to avoid listing the entire directory.  https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/sqs.html